# how to select or give a class name to createTextNode() tekst inside Li elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a shopping list, now I want to strike through the items when I click on it.
When I click on it now, the whole li item gets striked through(the marker and the `deletebutton` gets striked through now).
I want to give the tekst in the list items I created in this script a class, but I can't get it working.
this is the script where the list items is made :

```js
    function createListElement() {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
      li.classList.add("tekstje");
      ol.appendChild(li);
      input.value = "";
      
      var delBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");  // Create a <button> element
      delBtn.classList.add("deletebtn");              // Give a class name
      delBtn.innerHTML = "X";                         // Insert text
      li.appendChild(delBtn);                         // Append <button> to <LI>
    }
```

I tried the `classlist.add` method and giving it a P class, but that doesn't seem to work.
I also tried selecting it with :tekst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the CSS on the inner button. Or, just wrap the text within the `li` with a span and only add the strike through on the `span`.

```js
var ol = document.getElementById("theOl");
var input = document.getElementById("theInput");

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  li.classList.add("tekstje");
  ol.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";

  var delBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // Create a <button> element
  delBtn.classList.add("deletebtn"); // Give a class name
  delBtn.innerHTML = "X"; // Insert text
  delBtn.onclick = function () {
    delBtn.parentNode.classList.add("all-done");
  }
  li.appendChild(delBtn); // Append <button> to <LI>
}
```

```css
.all-done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.all-done button {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ol id="theOl"></ol>
<input id="theInput" value="test">
<button onclick="createListElement()">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! the option using <span> did it for me!